# can I use LoadTestShape to specify a custom parameter in my Locust.io tasks? (Python)

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I am finding Locust.io awesome for tweaking certain parameters that will trigger specific implementation behavior in my web application. I want to measure how performance changes based on different config parameters in my web application.
Adopting `LoadTestShapes` and `ticks` to simulate K6-style stages seemed the obvious solution. I could tinker with my custom parameter at each stage and get my test to show system response side by side.
Alas, the tick definition only seems to allow changing specific Locust parameters (#users, #spawns and which user classes).

At that point, I figured I could use `get_run_time()`, and code the expected behavior within my `HttpUser` subclass. Alas, I couldn't find a way to access that method directly from within my task. So, still no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are not running distributed, you can just overwrite a class attribute on your subclass. If you ARE running distributed, I'd recommend sending a custom message https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html?highlight=message#communicating-across-nodes (from your tick method or otherwise)

Comment: Thank you, Cyberwiz, I am not running distributed. Can you point me to an example of overwriting a class attribute in my subclass? Not sure if this is what I am already doing or if I am missing out on a feature/trick. Thanks

Comment: Just `YourUser.attribute = something`

Answer (score 0):

Not a fully-fledged answer, just my workaround. SO comment area does not provide enough space for code (now I know where the "overflow" part comes from), so here it goes. Essentially I coded my own stages by counting seconds from the beginning of the test with `time` and setting my custom parameter that will be picked up in creating the custom HTTP requests:

```
import time

start = time.time()

stages = [
    {"duration": 60, "cache_hit_percentage": 100},
    {"duration": 120, "cache_hit_percentage": 90},
    {"duration": 180, "cache_hit_percentage": 80},
    {"duration": 240, "cache_hit_percentage": 70},
    {"duration": 300, "cache_hit_percentage": 60},
    {"duration": 360, "cache_hit_percentage": 50},
    {"duration": 420, "cache_hit_percentage": 40}
]

elapsed = start - time.time()
for s in stages:
    if elapsed < s["duration"]:
        cache_hit_percentage = s["cache_hit_percentage"]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing and I guess this is what I need essentially. Could you please explain more how the param cache_hit_percentage has been passed to request ?

Comment: in my script I have two types of URLs. those that will trigger a certain caching layer in my server application and those that won't. The custom paramater allows me to simulate different kinds of load that are specific to the service I am testing. Hopefully I made sense.